# Does sharepoint web services use search service application?

Tags: search, web-services, enterprise-search

This may be a silly question but i'm going to ask it anyways.  I'm curious about using web services to find lists or list items when the search service isn't configured or even installed?

- Will this continue to work?
- Do the web services have any dependencies on service applications
  like Search?
- If there is no dependency then how exactly do the services locate
  lists and list items for example?

Thanks in advance!